# Order Broken on Feature Article page

Tags: articles, menu, featured-articles

I have a page displaying a list of Feature Articles.

It is set up as a Menu Item of type Feature Articles. IN the Layout, I have Article Order set to 'Article Order'.

When I have 5 articles on the page, they appear in the expected order.

When I add another, I got pagination (not wanted) so I increased the #Into Articles on the Articles Global settings, and then all Articles appeared without pagination. But, unfortunately, the order is broken.

If I remove the extra article, the ordering is restored.

If I remove one of the other articles, sometimes the ordering is restored, sometimes still broken. I have not been able to see a pattern.

How can I guarantee the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

The Feature Article menu item #Columns setting was empty, and by the look of the HTML generated it was trying to generate 2 columns but the template could only render one column, causing layout confusion.

By setting the #Columns setting to 1, this agrees with that the template was rendering, and solves the confusion. Sorting Sorted!